# Apigility file upload

Tags: php, zend-framework2, laminas-api-tools

I'm new to Zend's Apigility and I have problem with file upload.
I've created a new rest service and configured fields in the admin UI as described in Apigility documentation: https://apigility.org/documentation/recipes/upload-files-to-api

When trying to obtain any data from InputFilter i get only null values.

Resource controller

```
public function create($data)
    {
        $inputFilter = $this->getInputFilter();
        $data = $inputFilter->getValues();
        var_dump($data);
        //return $this->attachments->create($data);
    }
```

var_dump result

```
array(1) {
  ["filedata"]=>
  NULL
}
```

For testing purposes I'm using Postman extension for Chrome with Content-Type header set to 'multipart/form-data', and attached file to key: filedata.

I'm pretty sure, I can send files using json and base64_encode, but I would rather hold with it until it would be absolutely necessary.

Comment: Are you using apigility v 1.0.2, I know there were some issues with fileuploads before this version? see http://framework.zend.com/blog/apigility-1-0-2-released.html

Comment: Yes, I have recently performed update for whole project.

Answer (score 0):

For those who aren't aware, Apigility is a Zend Framework 2 based framework specifically made for Rest/Rpc API's.

To do file uploads, please refer to their documentation on the recent updates as noted by Jon Day.

Credit : https://apigility.org/documentation/recipes/upload-files-to-api

> How can you allow uploading files via your API?
>
> **Answer**
>
> Zend Framework 2 provides a variety of classes surrounding file upload
>   functionality, including a set of validators (used to validate whether
>   the file was uploaded, as well as whether it meets specific criteria
>   such as file size, extension, MIME type, etc.), a set of filters (used
>   to allow renaming an uploaded file, as well as, more rarely, to
>   manipulate the contents of the file), and file-upload-specific inputs
>   for input filters (because validation of files needs to follow
>   different rules than regular data).

Currently the limitation is that Apigility will only accept `multipart/form-data`

Using Xdebug I am getting the following out :

```
$data_array = $inputFilter->getValues();
$image = $data_array['images_data'];
```

The $image array looks like this :

```
   name = MemeCenter_1400658513231_337.jpg
   type = image/jpeg
   tmp_name = /tmp/phpzV3mWA
   error = 0
   size = 379580
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

1. Update apigility with composer. File upload is working in version 1.0.3
2. Use Postman to send files but with no headers.Just select form-data.It worked for me.
3. To move uploaded file use rename instead of move_uploaded_file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the option (`'magicFile' => false`) for the MimeType validator which fixes the problem without any modification at the zf library.